# Ask the user for 5 numbers and display a message saying whether the number was on the list or not

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that creates a random list, sorts that list, then asks a user for 5 numbers and uses a binary search to display message whether the number is in the list or not. I am getting the error message `BubbleSort(ran_list) Type Error:ran_list not defined`. Any help would be helpful, I thought `ran_list` is clearly defined in the `createList` function.

```
def createList():
    import random
    ran_list=[]

    for n in range(50):
        numbers=random.randint(1,100)
        ran_list.append(numbers)

     return ran_list

def myBubbleSort(ran_list):
    for i in range(len(ran_list),0,-1):
        for j in range(0,i-1):
            if ran_list[j]>ran_list[j+1]:
                temp=ran_list[j]
                ran_list[j]=ran_list[j+1]
                ran_list[j+1]=temp

    return ran_list

def myBinarySearch(value,ran_list):
    low=0
    high=len(ran_list)-1
    pos=-1

    while low<=high and pos==-1:
        mid=(low+high)//2

        if ran_list[mid]<value:
            low=mid+1

        elif ran_list[mid]>value:
            high=mid-1
        else:
            pos=mid

     return pos
```

'''
Main Program
'''

```
createList()
myBubbleSort(ran_list)

for i in range(5):
    value=int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    myBinarySearch(value,num_list)

    if pos==-1:
        print("The number is not in the list")

    else:
        print("The number is in the list")
```

Comment: You have not defined `ran_list` in your main program.

Answer (score 1):

`ran_list` is not defined when you try to pass it into `myBubbleSort()`. Change the first line of your main program to be `ran_list = createList()`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define many variables in your code. This is your edited code:

```
def createList():
    import random
    ran_list=[]

    for n in range(50):
        numbers=random.randint(1,100)
        ran_list.append(numbers)

    return ran_list

def myBubbleSort(ran_list):
    for i in range(len(ran_list),0,-1):
        for j in range(0,i-1):
            if ran_list[j]>ran_list[j+1]:
                temp=ran_list[j]
                ran_list[j]=ran_list[j+1]
                ran_list[j+1]=temp

    return ran_list

def myBinarySearch(value,ran_list):
    low=0
    high=len(ran_list)-1
    pos=-1

    while low<=high and pos==-1:
        mid=(low+high)//2

        if ran_list[mid]<value:
            low=mid+1

        elif ran_list[mid]>value:
            high=mid-1
        else:
            pos=mid

    return pos



ran_list = createList()                               # Was not assigned to ran_list
num_list = myBubbleSort(ran_list)                     # Same here..

for i in range(5):
    value=int(input("Please enter a number: "))    
    pos = myBinarySearch(value,num_list)              # Was not assigned

    if pos==-1:
        print("The number is not in the list")

    else:
        print("The number is in the list")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your code to :

```
ran_list = createList()
```

Also you should put `import random` at the top of your script

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am quite confused. How can ran_list=createList() by the first line of code, I can't call a function before I have defined it.

Comment: I meant in your main script. Also you should refer to @direnprobs solution. It is far better and has all your issues resolved